# JQuery UI slide effect creates a new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to enable an effect on my web app where a user clicks an "Edit" icon and a text box elegantly slides out horizontally immediately to the right of the icon. Currently it is sliding out, but not very elegantly, because when I click on the icon for some reason a new row is created in the browser below where I clicked (and all content below is bumped down). The text box slides out, and then bizarrely jumps back up to where I originally wanted it to go, and the new row created disappears.

Please note, however, that if I put the textbox on its own line so that it is fully left-justified against the margin, that it works just fine. But I want it to scroll it to the right of the icon.

This behavior is the same for IE8 and Firefox.

Here is the HTML:

```
<img src="../images/edit.gif" onclick="toggleNotebox()" style="cursor:pointer"/>
<span id="AddText" style="display:none">
    <input name="AddNoteText" id="TextBox" onkeypress="return addNote(event);" />
</span>
```

And here is the relevant Javascript:

```
function toggleNotebox() {
    var options = {};
    $('#AddText').toggle('slide', options, 500);
 }
```

Here is the jsbin.com URL to see this behavior in action: http://jsbin.com/alopu/edit

Comment: is this consistent across all the browsers you care about?  Can you put an example on http://jsbin.com/ ?

Comment: Yes and yes. See edits above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting a float: left on both elements.

http://jsbin.com/uzoqo

edit: for some reason the above works but if you try to edit it it doesn't show my changes to the code. not sure what happened.

Comment: you can also lose the "onClick" in your  markup and just set the `toggle()` function in the `document.ready` function

Comment: This works. FYI, I also had some other elements to the left of the icon, so I had to add a float:left to each of those, too, but in the end I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements, which spans and inputs are by default, don't honour explicit widths.  So jQuery's either changing the display of the animated element to block, or wrapping it in a block element so that that element can be animated.

That's why Samuel's change works - floated elements honour widths.